# Why can't we make a trait with non-method associated functions into a trait object?

Tags: rust, vtable, trait-objects

According to the [explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#method-has-no-receiver), Rust rejects to make a trait with non-method associated functions into a trait object.

> Methods that do not take a `self` parameter can’t be called since there won’t be a way to get a
> pointer to the method table for them.
>
> ```rust
> trait Foo {
>    fn foo() -> u8;
> }
> ```
>
> This could be called as `<Foo as Foo>::foo()`, which would not be able to pick an implementation.
>
> Adding a `Self: Sized` bound to these methods will generally make this compile.
>
> ```rust
> trait Foo {
>    fn foo() -> u8 where Self: Sized;
> }
> ```

Why can't we just put the address of the non-method associated function into the vtable, thus we can call it through the vtable and make the trait into a trait object too. It seems that there aren't any obstacles to dealing it this way.

I'd think this is a more elegant approach to cope with these traits rather than simply excluding them from making trait objects.

Comment: Given a `bar: Box<dyn Foo>`, how would you want to call `foo()` for `bar`? `bar.foo()` seems wrong, since it passes `bar` as the `self` parameter, but `foo()` doesn't take one.

Answer (score 2):

To get a vtable, you need an instance of the object. At this point, you already have an instance, so there is little advantage to not having the method taking `&self`.

It *can* have by not requiring static dispatch to have an instance; but this is a very minor thing, and nobody has even bothered to write an RFC for that. Not to mention that the syntax will need to be decided.

Comment: Sorry, I am still  confused about it. I'd think if we put the address of the non-method function into the vtable, wouldn't it be more a unified way to make a trait object? Since in this way, we needn't to reject a trait with non-method functions into a trait object.

Comment: If you control the trait yourself, adding `&self` to an associated function is a minor issue, but less so if you are using a trait from a library.

Comment: @SvenMarnach If you think that's important, you're welcome to send an RFC :)

Comment: I don't have a use case for this. I'm just saying that it seems plausible someone else has.